Getting this issue while connection with git to spring cloud config server o server port 8888
I tried running a Spring Cloud Config Server application, expecting it to start successfully and be able to fetch configuration properties from the specified URL (http://localhost:8888). However, I encountered an error where the application was unable to connect to the Config Server, resulting in a "Connection refused" error.
What I tried:

Ensured that the Spring Cloud Config Server was correctly configured in the application properties.
Checked that the server was supposed to be running on http://localhost:8888.
Attempted to restart the application to resolve any transient issues.

What I expected:
I expected the application to successfully connect to the Spring Cloud Config Server and load the necessary configuration properties without any connection issues.

at the very least please show your application.properties and complete logs
